# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null value after joining two tables in C#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, null

After I joined the table in my codes the error "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null value " occurred.

Please have a look on my codes and please help. I tried to look for the answer in the google but still didn't get what I wanted to do.

Here's my codes which causes the  mentioned error:

```
private static string m_sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NomsConnection"].ConnectionString;
private static string
    m_sReport = "SELECT r.[RequestID],r.[RequestDate],r.[PARNumber],r.[StatusID],r.[PurchaseComment]"   // 0 - 4
                + ",r.[UID],r.[MyUID],r.[FullName],r.[Email]"                                         // 5 - 8
                + ",r.[EntityName],r.[DepartmentName],r.[DepartmentID]"                                 // 9 - 11
                + ",r.[LastBy]"                                                                         // 12
                + ",r.[ProgramID],r.[ProgramCode],r.[ProgramName],r.[CostCenterCode]"                   // 13 - 16
                + ",p.[PartDesc],p.[SupplierID],p.[AccountType],p.[CurrName],p.[PartQuantity],p.[PiecePrice]"
                + "FROM [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Requests] r "
                + "JOIN [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Parts] p on p.[RequestID] = r.[RequestID]"
                + "WHERE [CountryName] IN ('Philippines')";




 public static List<NomsPRRequest> LoadPRRequestFromDB(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
            string sSrcipt = m_sReport + "and [RequestDate] between '" + from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' and '" + to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'";
            Dictionary<long, NomsPRRequest> data = new Dictionary<long, NomsPRRequest>();
            long key;
            double dAmount;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(m_sConnectionString)) {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSrcipt, con)) {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    key = reader.GetInt64(0);
                    if (!data.ContainsKey(key)) {
                        data.Add(key, new NomsPRRequest() {
                            RequestID = key
                            ,RequestDate = reader.GetDateTime(1)
                            ,PARNumber = reader.GetString(2)
                            ,StatusID = reader.GetInt64(3)
                            ,FullName = reader.GetString(7)
                            ,LastBy = reader.GetString(12)
                            ,ProgramName = reader.GetString(14)
                            ,ItemList = new List<NomsPRItem>()
                            ,TotalAmount = 0.0
                        });
                    }

                    dAmount = (double)reader.GetDecimal(21) * (double)reader.GetDecimal(22);

                    data[key].TotalAmount += dAmount;

                     data[key].ItemList.Add(new NomsPRItem() {
                        RequestID = key,
                        PartDesc = reader.GetString(17)
                        ,SupplierID = reader.GetString(18)
                        ,AccountType = reader.GetString(19)
                        ,CurrName = reader.GetString(20)
                        ,PartQuantity = (double)reader.GetDecimal(21)
                        ,PiecePrice = (double)reader.GetDecimal(22)
                        ,Amount = dAmount

                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return data.Values.ToList();

    }
}
```

---

Since the column [LastBy] in my database only has the null values .. I just added what Luann said :) .. Thanks for sharing Luann !

```
 data[key].ItemList.Add(new NomsPRItem() {
    ,RequestDate = reader.GetDateTime(1)
                ,PARNumber = reader.GetString(2)
                ,StatusID = reader.GetInt64(3)
                ,FullName = reader.GetString(7)
                ,LastBy = reader.IsDBNull(12) ? null : reader.GetString(12)
                ,ProgramName = reader.GetString(14)
                ,ItemList = new List<NomsPRItem>()
                ,TotalAmount = 0.0

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `reader.IsDBNull` before reading the value of a nullable column.

For example:

```
PartDesc = reader.IsDBNull(17) ? null : reader.GetString(17)
```

Comment: Thank you @Luann ! That was the code I was waiting for.

Comment: @Mijevoli: why do you wait for a better answer if this answer solved your issue? I guess you don't know what i meant with "accept", you can look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Got it ! I'm just a newbie here ! Thanks for guiding @TimSchmelter !